# How can I convert a string like 3hours26minutes33seconds into HH:MM:SS format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, datetime, string-to-datetime

I have a string '3hours26minutes33seconds' and I need to convert this into HH:MM:SS format. 
I tried using dateutil.parser.parse to no avail.

Comment: is the hour part always < 24 ? or could you also have e.g. '33hours26minutes33seconds'?

Comment: Is the order fixed, i.e., could you simply replace all runs of non-numeric characters with `:`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `datetime` and its `strptime` function to convert it to a datetime object:

```py
import datetime

string = "3hours26minutes33seconds"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Hhours%Mminutes%Sseconds")
```

Then you format that datetime into the desired string format with `strftime`:

```py
date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```